# Create a custom CRS based on a known PSM

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system

We have some CAD data that's based off a [Permanent Survey Mark](https://www.business.qld.gov.au/industry/titles-property-construction/surveying/permanent-survey-marks) (PSM) (details below). How do I create a CRS so that the data can be brought into GDA94 (4283)?

PSM: 110326
GDA94
Lat: 12D 39M 50.5201"S
Lon: 141D 50M 49.8383"E
E: 591994.116
N: 8599867.976
Zone: 54
Order: 1st Class: A
Adjustment: GSA - WEIPA Control

This seems to be the reverse process of [How to define a CRS using a projection rotated about a given point](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/23576/how-to-define-a-crs-using-a-projection-rotated-about-a-given-point?rq=1) or am I mistaken?

Basically, the question is how to bring a dataset that is fixed to a position that has GPS coordinates (is real world) into real world coordinates as a whole.

Comment: Oh a *local datum*, I see this a lot in surveying data; in ArcGis you create a world file for the CAD drawing and enter the Easting, Northing then 1's and 0's for scale and rotation (scale = 1, rotation = 0) and Arc puts it where it needs to go (or close enough). As for QGIS I'm not sure. You could try converting to Esri Shape and follow instructions http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/21256/how-to-easily-shift-all-features-in-a-vector-dataset

Comment: Following http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/83861/using-customized-coordinate-system-for-archaeological-site-data , make sure to use decimal degrees and negative latitudes for your reference point.